# Exclude readme.md from Vuepress

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuepress

I'm trying to exclude the `README.md` from Vuepress so I can use it for Github documentation. I'm using `index.md` as my homepage.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried something like this, but it's totally a blind shot as I don't know what the loader is called:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
   config.module
      .rule('md')
      .exclude
      .add('README')
}
```

Comment: Can you add complete config?

Answer (score 0):

You could structure your repository like so, effectively moving the VuePress app down one level (in this example, inside of the "site" directory):

```
├── site
│   ├── .vuepress
│   │   ├── components
│   │   ├── theme
│   │   ├── public
│   │   ├── styles
│   │   ├── config.js
│   ├── docs
│   │   ├── subDocs (Note: Nested docs)
│   │   └── README.md
│   ├── README.md (Note: The home page of the docs)
│   └── package.json
└── README.md (Note: GitHub documentation)
```